# 404 Fetching Error when tying to update xubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, update-manager

when I use this command `sudo do-release-upgrade` I always get the error which is given below

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources                                                                                            

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                     

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe i386 Packages                                                                                      

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe Sources                                                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                                              
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                                              
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com xenial/universe i386 Packages                                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]                                                                                                              
Fetched 2.874 kB in 6s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                      

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] 
, W:Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/Packages 
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80] 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or 
old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What about your internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the access to one particular file from default/current mirror was very slow.

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
```

I tested a [bunch of mirrors](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com) and used the one that was quick and worked.